# Why is a state change not invoking a react act() error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library, testing-library

Most people are searching for how to get rid of react `act()` errors in testing. I'm wondering the opposite. I have code that induces a state change. That state change should trigger a re-render in react (and it does). However, I did not act() wrap that state change, and an act() error was not emitted.  Why is this?

Consider the following goofy component:

```js
export function SweetTextboxBro() {
  const [text, setText] = React.useState("");
  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="text"
        role="input"
        name="sweetbox"
        onChange={(evt) => {
          setText(evt.currentTarget.value);
        }}
        value={text}
      />
      <p>{text}</p>
    </>
  );
}
```

Now, consider this minimal test:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import { SweetTextboxBro } from "../SweetTextboxBro";
import { sleep } from "../timing";

test("it emits act errors", async () => {
  render(<SweetTextboxBro />); // should internally call act()
  const textbox = screen.getByRole("input");
  const input = "weeee";
  // begin state change!
  userEvent.type(textbox, input);
  await sleep(200);
  // state updated! the DOM  has changed! but no act() error... is emitted
  expect(await screen.findByText(input)).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Act errors occur when react re-renders content outside of an act() call. I'm unclear why this case does not apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React Testing Library wraps `fireEvent` and `userEvent` in a call to `act` internally. In addition, React automatically handles state changes generated from click events, meaning they wouldn't trigger `act` warnings in the first place.

`act` should only ever be needed when using asynchronous code that runs as a result of a resolved promise, e.g., when making API calls.

This means that you don't even need to `await` for the input to change in your test. The following test would also pass.

```js
test("it emits act errors", () => {
  render(<SweetTextboxBro />); // should internally call act()
  const textbox = screen.getByRole("input");
  const input = "weeee";
  userEvent.type(textbox, input);
  expect(screen.getByText(input)).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```